# Simple JavaScript function that asks the user for correct answer only 5 times?

Tags: javascript, loops, input, prompt

I am trying to develop a very simple function with JavaScript that prompts the user to input a number, and then gives them 5 chances to guess the square of the given number.

So for example, if the user puts in 6 in the first prompt, they should put in 36 in the second prompt, but if they fail to make it right, they are getting an error saying that the guessed number is wrong. And they are limited to only 5 chances, so after that, the program does not prompt a user again.

I tried to do something like this to keep things simple:

```
var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Guess its square now in 5 tries");
if (input2 == input*input) {
    alert("Good!");
} else {
    prompt("Wrong, enter again!");
}
```

Am I on a right path here? I mean it is not doing what I want it to do, but I am really stuck at this point. Have no idea how to loop it 5 times, or what to do next.

Comment: look up `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket:

```
var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Guess its square now in 5 tries")); //<--- here

if (input2 == input*input) {
  alert("Good!");
} else {
  prompt("Wrong, enter again!");
}
```

... and you need a loop. The simplest to understand is `for`:

```js
var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Guess its square now in 5 tries"));

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (input2 == input*input) {
    alert("Good!");
    i = 5;
  } else {
    input2 = prompt("Wrong, enter again!")
  }
}
```

Comment: I was not missing a closing bracket in the actual code, so that's why it was working, just a typo here. However, this "for" loop is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Very simple, yet does its job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function guessSquare() {
    var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
    var c = 5;
    var message = "Guess its square now in 5 tries";
    (function receiveAnswer() {
        var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt(message));
        if (input2 == input * input) {
            alert("Good!");
        } else {
            c--;
            if (c === 0) {
                alert("Ran out of attempts!");
            } else {
                message = "Wrong, enter again! " + c + " attempts left!";
                receiveAnswer();
            }
        }
    })();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making it a bit more complex, this is very useful as well, with the attempt counter and stuff. Thanks for the effort, but as I am still a newbie to this, I was looking for the simplest possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `do-while`

```js
var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Guess its square now in 5 tries"));

var tries = 1;
do {
  if (input2 == input * input) {
    alert("Good!");
    break;
  } else {
    prompt("Wrong, enter again!");
  }
} while (++tries < 5);
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I never thought nesting an if-else statement in a do-while was possible.. This is very simple and useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a number", "Enter here"));
var input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Guess its square now in 5 tries"));

var tries = 0;
do {
  if (input2 == input * input) {
    alert("Good!");
    break;
  } else {
    input2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Wrong, enter again!"));
  }
} while (++tries < 5);
```